# How to get only last selected option value from multiple select using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have one `select` which have `multiple` parameter as well. I need to get which `option` is selected last. I had tried `$(this).val()`. But this is giving array of selected option. Not the option which one I have selected just now.
Here is the form code.

```
<select name="services[]" multiple="true" class="form-control js-services" required="required" id="services">
 <option value="Checked">Check All</option>
 <option value="179" data-text="This is service" data-duration="10" data-cost="6.5">This is service</option>
 <option value="187" data-text="Service A+" data-duration="15" data-cost="10">Service A+ 
 </option>
</select>
```

And this is what I have done so far,

```
$(document).on("change",'.js-services',function(){
 $(this).find('option:selected').data('text');
 $(this).val();
});
```

From above code, this line `$(this).find('option:selected').data('text');` shows the option which is selected first in the list. And this line `$(this).val();` shows me an array containing all the selected `options value`. While I need to get the value which is just selected. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: I presume you mean "which was selected most recently" - rather than the last in the list

Comment: You need to store the (multiple) value before and then compare in the change event.  There's no "before"/"after" in the change event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if I don't know for what this is useful, you can remember the last selected values and compare on new select

```
let selected = [];

$(document).on("change",'.js-services',function(){
    $(this).find('option:selected').data('text');
    const values = $(this).val();
    // Remove all non selected from selected array if user has deselected something
    selected = selected.filter((value) => values.includes(value));
    // get value which is not in selected list
    const lastSelected = values.filter((value) => !selected.includes(value));
    // push to selected array
    selected.push(lastSelected[0]);
    console.log(lastSelected);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qeaL4fo3/

Answer (score 0):

**this** in `$(this).val()` stands for `.js-services` class which is given to the `select` tag.

You have already found the current selection value in `$(this).find('option:selected').data('text')`, which could be assigned to a variable and viewed in console as shown below:

```js
$(document).on("change",'.js-services',function(){
 var currSelect = $(this).find('option:selected').data('text');
 console.log(currSelect); //The selected value would be shown
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/art49odk/1/

Answer (score 0):

I tried many ways and this is the only way that works

```
$('selector').on('select:select', function (e) {
            var data = e.params.data;
            console.log(data);
            });
        });
```

'select2:select' for select2